# How display notification on IOS 8 like in google maps in navigation time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, notifications

How can show notification like in google maps when navigation enabled and application works in background?
Needs something like that:
[image: Google Maps Navigation background notification]

Or like Skype background notification:

[image: Skype background notification]

Comment: That's a system notification that appears automatically in your app is running in the background and is using location services, AFAIK. There is nothing you can or need to do to get this.

Comment: Same function also have Skype app (in calling moment), but skype seems not using location services.